# Find New Buyers, and Returning Buyers from the Orders tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an existing E-commerce database with the rather standard sales tables. The relevant tables are:

1. Orders table.
   The fields are like:
   OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ...
2. Customers table.
   CustoerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, ...

I need to find two values, namely:

1. Total new buyers (within a certain time period *)

   - Basically, those are fist time buyers within a certain time period
2. Total returning buyers (within a certain time period *)

   - Basically, these are buyers who have bought before, prior to the time period
   - time period, we will provide as the inputs, such as within 1 week

My database is in MySQL.

**Question:**

What is the easiest and most efficient way to get the two totals?
1. Total new buyers
2. Total returning buyers

Do I need to write a program in PHP? Or I can simply use SQL statements to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done purely in SQL:

#### Number of First time buyers:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN <startdate> AND <enddate>
/* Buyers with only one order record */
AND CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
```

#### Number of repeat buyers:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN <startdate> AND <enddate>
/* Buyers with more than one order record */
AND CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: I think this will work. Thank you so much Michael... will try this code out!

Answer (score 0):

Both! You have to write SQL statement that return  data from the Database and call the statement from inside a PHP script to deal with it. The SQL statement make you able to retrive data and the PHP code make you able to menage and eventually presetn data on your web page (cenverting it into HTML language).

This is the common scenario, but if you need a more detailed procedure with code, use [google](http://get%20data%20from%20mysql%20with%20php) and have a nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

Total new buyers
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c, Orders o
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
AND c.CustomerID not in(SELECT o1.CustomerID from Orders o1)

Total returning buyers
Total new buyers
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c, Orders o
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
AND c.CustomerID in(SELECT o1.CustomerID from Orders o1)

you can add time frame to both queries